# Create List Item that contains lookup fields

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to reproduce this request who works with SP REST API with MS graph:

```http
POST https://.../_api/web/lists/getbytitle('...')/items

{
  "PSAuthorId":"someId",
  "PSAuthorlabel":"...",
  "PSApproverId":"someId",
  "PSApproverlabel":"..."
  ...
}
```

`PSAuthorId` and `PSApproverId` are lookup fields that are returned by Graph as `PSAuthorLookupId`, `PSApproverLookupId`

When i try to add a `ListItem` with via Microsoft Graph:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/.../lists/.../items

{
  "fields": 
  {
     "PSAuthorId": "someid",
     "PSAuthorlabel": "...",
     "PSApproverlabel": "..."
  }
}
```

I got this error:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "invalidRequest",
        "message": "Field 'PSAuthorId' is not recognied",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "...",
            "date": "2017-11-25T13:42:47"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the same result from both the `/v1.0` and `/beta` endpoints.

Is there any way to add these (lookup) fields to a `ListItem`?

**Edit**

To clarify, Here is my result that works with old SharePoint Rest API:

```http
GET https://.../_api/web/lists/getbytitle('...')/items

{
    "d": {
        "results": [
            {
                ...
                "Id": 71,
                "AuthorId": 33,
                "EditorId": 33,
                "PSAuthorId": 33,
                "PSAuthorStringId": "33",
                "PSApproverId": 60
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my result that works with Microsoft Graph API:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/.../lists/.../items?select=id&expand=fields

{
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "77",
            "fields": {
                ...
                "id": "77",
                "AuthorLookupId": "33",
                "EditorLookupId": "33",
                "PSAuthorLookupId": "33",
                "PSApproverLookupId": "60"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

For lookup fields, with GET i ot informations with #LookupId, but for POST it says me that Field * is not recognied.

I've tried with PSAuthorLookupId, AuthorLookupId, PSAuthorId, PSAuthor.Id, ... but allways the same error.

Comment: To clarify your scenario - are you looking to add a new field to your SharePoint List during item creation ('PSAuthorId')?

Comment: Not Realy, PsAuthor is a lookup field that contains an Id, I'm trying to set the id of the lookup field. I've edited my post with more informations.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with lookup field updates when the target field was a user. Hopefully it's working for you now!